# SQL How to display text next to values in column

Tags: mysql, sql

Ask for your help. I work with MySQL and cannot figure out how to display text near value like this

```
ID | Value
----------
1  | 100 unit(s)
----------
2  | 200 unit(s)
----------
3  | 250 unit(s)
```

Currectly I have only this

```
ID | Value
----------
1  | 100 
----------
2  | 200 
----------
3  | 250
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into Select query with concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CONCAT(Value, " unit(s)") AS Value
FROM <your_table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have at least tried to google around and you would have found answer in couple of trials.

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT(value,' unit(s)') AS value from <YOUR_TABLE>;
```

Kindly read more about it [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php).